# How to separte HTML code from Ext JS code like css?

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

Is there any way to separate html code from Ext JS code?. For example I am writing some html code inside grid panel js file. Here i need to move html code to some other file and reference that to grid panel. Like how we are doing for css. We are keeping css file separately and referring class(css) to view files.

```
Ext.define('SomeGrid', {
columns:[{},{},{}],
 plugins: [
        {
            ptype: 'rowexpander',
            rowBodyTpl: [
                '<table class="customers">',
                '  <tr>',
                '    <th>Name</th>'
                '  </tr>',
                '  <tr>',
                '  <td>{name}</td>',
                '  </tr>'
            ]
        }
    ],
})
```

Comment: What type of code is it. Are you showing some html template inside it?

Comment: Yes. I am displaying some content in the screen by using HTML tags

Comment: Can you post code related to your question , need to check what type of html code you are saying.

Comment: I have added sample code with question. @Tejas